# Ember data. Reload data when visiting a topic from list of topics

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the topics.index, I send list of topics as JSON without sending relationship ids (A topic has many posts, many users, edits, likes, etc etc which I do not show in the topics.index hence I do not want to render all the relationship ids when visiting topics.index using App.Topic.find())

So whenever a topic link is clicked, ember-data does not fetch from topic/:topic_id if it finds that the specific topic is already loaded (but this time, all the relationships are necessary). Is there a way we can force ember-data to reload every time when we go to a new link, irrespective of whether the data is already loaded or not?

Reloading also reduces number of requests made to the server.

Let's say A topic has many posts and many comments:
When rendering list of topics we store post_ids and comment_ids in each of the topic, when rendering a topic,ember-data will now make two requests to the server. One to fetch all the posts with the post_ids and all the comments.

If we force to reload, we can sideload all the relationship data with one request instead of many to fetch the hasMany or belongsTo data.

Answer (score 1):

Ember Data currently lazy loads associations. So you should be able to send all the ids in your initial json.

When clicking on a specific topic, you can request the record again (using `store.reloadRecord`) and sideload all the models that you need, or simply let Ember Data requests them if they are used.

Comment: where should we use the store.reloadRecord? in setupController? During the time we request reload to obtaining records from server, Ember-Data will also side load associations with available ids so this might not prevent multiple requests for loading associations.

Comment: when you define the `model` for your `TopicRoute`. You can check if the record is already in the store with something like `store.hasReferenceForId(App.Topic, topic_id)`. This isn't a great solution as you will reload your data each time you reach that topic.

Comment: I'm building sports related website and hence I would like reload data each time. model function is not called always.

Comment: You may not have declared a resource for your route (see http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/ )